# Splitting and rejoining a trace to reduce resistance

Tags: pcb, routing, trace

I'm teaching an embedded systems class and a question came up I've never considered.  We were discussing the idea of "necking down" a trace to get through a tight spot and someone asked if it made sense to route two (or more) traces to create an effectively wider (and so lower-resistance) path.

This would seem like a really bad idea for high-speed signals as it could cause various forms of interference.  But if the trace lengths are the same (and maybe the widths too), it feels like it should be fine for most signals.  But don't think I've ever seen such a design and it makes me nervous to suggest it would be okay.  A web search turned up nothing useful (maybe because I'm using the wrong words?).

Anyone have thoughts (or ideally references to a formal discussion) on this topic?

Comment: Ultimately it becomes a power or ground plane. Think about it.

Answer (score 5):

Low level signals don't care what width of trace they're on. As long as the trace is wide enough that it can be printed reliably, even allowing for process tolerances, then it's wide enough. The board manufacturer will advise what the minimum size is that can be used for their process and your budget.

Power supply traces need to be wide enough at all points for the current they are carrying, and be wide enough on average, or short enough, for voltage drop from end to end. Do run parallel tracks if more copper is needed.

RF tracks, including high speed logic signals, must be designed with constant impedance, which usually means constant width. There is a tolerance allowed on this, and very short areas of necking down can often be tolerated, or turned into filters with judicious widening of nearby track.

Comment: Agree with everything Neil_UK said here.  Just want to add that a signal integrity simulation & modeling tool is your best friend here.  Use it liberally!

Answer (score 3):

If the traces carry high-speed signals then impedance is generally a concern. Running parallel traces will not help to control the impedance (and can make everything worse) since the width and the distance between tracks (especially when differential signals are involved) should be the same along the way.

Instead of running multiple traces for the same net in parallel running one wider trace would be easier during PCB design. Why would someone run two or more traces for the same net from one point to another?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this can be seen on some products. For example when routing power supply trace to staggered multi-row pin through hole connectors, like DE-15.

To allow enough current to pass to a connector pin, a wide supply trace can be split into two for a few millimeters to route around another connector pad and join them at the supply pin pad again.

Maybe suitable on some other high current trace which controls a load too, but generally this is not done on high speed digital or analog signals that need to have controlled trace impedance.

On the other hand, given enough PCB copper layers, it might not be necessary to split a single trace in a single 2D plane, as it can be done in 3D.

Multiple layers can have a single narrow trace but they all add up in parallel to a low-inductance and low impedance high current path.